# Potential energy of a particle moving in a circle

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, potential-energy

Consider a particle under the influence of a conservative force field such that that it moves in a circle of radius $r$. Its potential energy is a function of $r$ and the angle $\theta$ made by the radius vector with the horizontal , given by- 
$U(r,\theta)= Ar^3\cos{\theta}$, where $A$ is a constant . We have to find the centripetal as well as the tangential force acting on the particle at any particular angle $\theta$.

How should I approach ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should approach as you would do with every other case of force determined by a potential: take the gradient of your potential $U$, that's the force! Then you remember that for a circular motion the centripetal acceleration must be $\vec{v}^2/r$ and you are practically done. The only thing that deserves a little bit of care in this case is the fact that we are working with polar coordinates and the gradient, as you should know, **is not**:
$$\frac{\partial U}{\partial r}\hat{r}+\frac{\partial U}{\partial \theta}\hat{\theta}$$